# binding image in windows phone 8

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8

Can i bind image to xaml without needing to use image source (the predominant method) which it is (In xaml page):

```
<Image Height="170" Width="220" Source="{Binding Source=Img}" ></Image>
```

because i have image converted from byte array and doesn't have any name or source. 
like here:

```
Image Img = new Image();
Img=ByteArraytoBitmap(ob0[0].Img.ToArray());
```

---

```
public BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a BitmapImage property on your object (the class of ob0[0])  and then the bitmap image can be directly be binded to the source of the Image (Note that the binding should be  `Source="{Binding Img}`" and not `Source="{Binding Source=Img}"`.

The other solution would for you to create an attached property, something like this should work:

```
public class MyAttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ByteArraySourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ByteArraySource", typeof (Byte[]), typeof (MyAttachedProperty), new PropertyMetadata(default(Byte[],byteArraySource)))

        private static void byteArraySource(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = d as Image;
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                img.Source = ByteArraytoBitmap((Byte[]) e.NewValue);
            }
        }

    public static BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    public static void SetByteArraySource(UIElement element, Byte[] value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ByteArraySourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static Byte[] GetByteArraySource(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Byte[]) element.GetValue(ByteArraySourceProperty);
    }
}
```

then to do the binding you can just use it like this:

```
<Image Height="170" Width="220" local:MyAttachedProperty.ByteArraySource="{Binding Img}" ></Image>
```